# How do you remove special characters before uploading a file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave x Rails. Basically, I'm facing some problems with Amazon S3 string matching & I think it would just be easier to remove all the special characters, such as brackets & accents, (and spaces) before uploading the file.

So, what I'd like to know is how do you remove special characters from a file's filename before uploading the file in rails?

Thank you in advance

---

**Solved. For anyone else who's facing the same or similar problem, read my solution in my answer below. Cheers :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for anyone else, this is how I solved my problem: I basically used "encodeURI/encodeURIComponent" in my js file ("URI.escape" for my controller) to send my file to S3 already encoded & that way the S3 signature will match my string

Comment: How do you change a filename with JS? You can't actually do that for security reasons?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `parameterize` method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm aware of this but I was looking for a way to do this before uploading the file. How would you parameterize the filename before uploading the file?

Comment: Well, I've never used Carrierwave but I'd guess you do something like `file = whatever.to_file(filename).parameterize.underscore` then `file.send` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this answer doesn't fit my question

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the Carrierwave Method: filename in your *_uploader.rb:

```
  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    original_filename.gsub(/([\s\-_\[\]\{\}\*\']|%20)+/i, "-") if original_filename
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your Uploader Class and find the bit of code at the bottom for dealing with filenames.  Perhaps you can call the previously mentioned to_params method there:

```
# Override the filename of the uploaded files:
# Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    original_filename.to_param if original_filename?
  end
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Customize-your-version-file-names) if you need more elaborate customization

Comment: I''ve modified carrierwave so much at this point that this probably won't work for me but thank you @kspector

Answer (score 0):

please using regex to remove the params.

```
word = "did & I ^% helped"
word.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]/i, '')
result => "didIhelped"
```